# alert dialogue during a process with javascript

Tags: javascript, dialog, progress-bar

using **ASP .Net MVC 4.0** , **vs10** , **MSSQL 2008**

I have a stored procedure, which is executed in one of my page. it generally takes 30 to 50 second to execute. I want to show a alert dialogue where an gif image will be loaded during this process time. I am executing stored procedure with sqlcommand. The process started on clicking Process button. after finishing the process, the page returns another view.

I have poor knowledge of javascript, so please show me a simple way.

**EDIT:**

Is it possible to show an image on buttonclick an do other codebehind process?

**Like:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showImage() {
        document.getElementById('Processing').style.visibility = visible;
    }
</script>

<div id="progessbar">
     <img alt="Processing" src="../../Images/Processing2.gif" id="Processing" style="visibility:hidden"/>
</div>
```

Comment: An `alert` stops execution of the current script... You can make an AJAX request and use a modal dialog  to show the "alert" without stopping execution until the response comes back successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to accomplish what you're trying to do in a traditional `MVC` fashion since the request takes a long time. This is better accomplished using AJAX which processes your request asynchronously. I recommend also using jQueryUI dialog or any modal to show a progress indicator, or even any custom JS.

I like [jQuery BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) personally to create the modal for me but that's just a preference.

```
/** Using a wrapper to show/hide the progress indicator.
    Swap the blockUI with any library or custom JavaScript for displaying the progress indicator.
 */
var showProgress = function() {
    $.blockUI({ message: '<img src="progressImage.gif" />' });
};

var hideProgress = function() {
    $.unblockUI();
;}

/** Trigger to submit the form */
$('#submit').click(function() {
    /** Show an indicator before making an AJAX request*/
    showProgress();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/someEndpoint',
        data: $.toJSON({/* some JSON param */}),
        type: 'POST', 
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 50000 /** Override timeout in ms accordingly */

    }).done(function(data){
        /** Remove the indicator once the request has succeeded and process returned data if any. */
        hideProgress();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The concept stays the same. The code behind process will take place on your endpoint when the AJAX request is made. In my example above, you can change the `showProgress()` to use your custom progress image as the indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ajax` for your process. It ll make the parallel processing for "showing gif" and completing your desired code. 
You can use `JQuery-AJAX` with page methods this way: [1]: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

The success callback contains a parameter with the returning data.

or you can try simply this

```
var actionURL = "(Your disired action e.g /index.jsp)"
$.ajax({
cache:false,
url: actionURL,
beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType( 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8' );
    $("#progessbar").show();
    //Here you can write any code to execute before the action like gif loading etc
},
success: function( data ) {
    alert("Success Conditions");
    //"data" is what u gets from your target. You can see by alert(data); here
    //Here you can write any code which you want to execute on finding the required action successfully
},
complete: function(){
    alert("Complete Conditions");
    $("#progessbar").hide();
    //Here you can write any code which you want to execute on completion of the required action you given in actionURL
},
error: function(){  
    alert("Error Conditions");
}
});
```

NOTE: alerts are just for explanation, you can write your own code also
For this code you have to include `jquery` plugins. which can be downloaded from their official site [l]: http://jquery.com/